# What is causing the purple background behind the Tabs in my TabBar?

Tags: flutter

I have a TabBar that keeps showing a light purple color that I need to remove or make transparent. Attached is a screenshot of the problem and below is the code.  I can't figure out what is causing the purple area. If anyone can help me understand how to target it and make it transparent, I would greatly appreciate the help.[image]

```
class LeaderboardDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const LeaderboardDrawer({super.key});

  @override
  State<LeaderboardDrawer> createState() => _LeaderboardDrawerState();
}

class _LeaderboardDrawerState extends State<LeaderboardDrawer>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController? tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(
      length: 2,
      animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<TourPlayerBloc, TourPlayerState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is TourPlayerLoaded) {
          return SafeArea(
            child: Theme(
              data: ThemeData(
                drawerTheme: DrawerThemeData(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: Drawer(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                child: state.friends == null
                    ? Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Invite friends to play using your tour code: ${state.quizPlayDoc!.tourCode}}',
                        ),
                      )
                    : Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Material(
                            color: Colors.brown,
                            child: TabBar(
                              indicatorWeight: 6.0,
                              indicatorColor: Colors.amber,
                              controller: tabController,
                              dividerHeight: 35,
                              tabs: [
                                Material(
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  child: Tab(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'FRIENDS',
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 18,
                                      ).copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'TOP 100',
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                    ).copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
                              child: TabBarView(
                                controller: tabController,
                                children: [
                                  Scoreprogress(
                                    state.friends!,
                                    state.quizPlayDoc,
                                  ),
                                  Scoreprogress(
                                    state.quizPlayDocsList!,
                                    state.quizPlayDoc,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

Widget Scoreprogress(List<QuizPlayDoc> listdata, userDoc) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: listdata.length,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      bool isUser = false;
      if (listdata[index].playerId == userDoc.playerId) {
        isUser = true;
      }
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isUser ? Colors.amber[50] : null,
          border: const Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12)),
        ),
        child: index == 0
            ? ListTile(
                leading: Column(
                  children: [
                    SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/crown-tipped-min.svg',
                      width: 35,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '${index + 1}',
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                title: Text(
                  listdata[index].nickname!,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge,
                ),
                subtitle: Text('${listdata[index].score.toString()} Points'),
              )
            : ListTile(
                leading: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                  child: Text(
                    '${index + 1}',
                    style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  listdata[index].nickname!,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge,
                ),
                subtitle: Text('${listdata[index].score.toString()} Points'),
              ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is showing because of the `dividerHeight:35`. You can override the `dividerColor` based on your need.

```dart
TabBar(
  dividerColor: Colors.green,
  indicatorWeight: 35.0,
```

or

```dart
child: Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
      dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [ThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html)